# UIImageView in ScrollView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I'm trying add UIImageViews to the ScrollView to get horizontaly pagging effect.

```
    let pagesScrollViewSize = scrollView.frame.size
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count), pagesScrollViewSize.height)


    for var index = 0; index < 3; ++index {
        var frame = containerView.bounds
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * CGFloat(index)
        frame.origin.y = 0.0

        let newPageView = UIImageView(image: pageImages[index])

        newPageView.frame = frame
        newPageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

        scrollView.addSubview(newPageView)
    }
```

Here is my layout:

[image]

But on phone/emulator image is scaled to ScrollView height. I want scale image to scrollview width, so on one page will be one image.

[image]

Comment: Did you try creating the `ScrollView` longer than the `ViewController`?

Comment: @Buster scrollview is working correctly, as you see I'm setting contentsize    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesScrollViewSize.width * CGFloat(pageImages.count), pagesScrollViewSize.height)

Answer (score 0):

To scale image to scrollview width you need to resize (scale image to width) + crop image first. Setting content mode to `ScaleAspectFit` will only "*...scale the content to fit the size of the view by maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent*".

Comment: This will be ok for me if above and below will be transparent area. It is possible to scale that images in that way that width will equal scrollview width and above and below will be that transparent area?

Comment: if you want to fit portrait image entirely, you need to resize scroll view. if you want just to scale it by width, you will need to crop image

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using autolayout in my Storyboard but I was adding new view's without adding constrains. So I've added this photos manualy in storyboard like was shown here: [UIScrollView Paging Autolayout & Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788514/uiscrollview-paging-autolayout-storyboard)